# How to use variables/values as arguments for imported modules/functions

Tags: python, function, module

The context of this is that I'm trying to make a common module that can be imported into other programs. The code here is from the common module. The idea of this function is that it checks if the value given from the main program is a positive integer or not.

```
def checkpoints(x):
        if x.isdigit() == False:
                num = print('Please enter valid interger.')
                return num
        else:
                print('all g')
                return
```

Another question is that is it possible to use a variable from the main program and have that set as an argument in an imported function/module? How would I do that?

Comment: let me try to restate your question: are you asking how a python script could use this module/library by passing down/through a variable, such as `x`? Please help by making your central question more clear

Answer (score 0):

To import variables and functions from files, treat the file name as a module. This only works if the 2 files are in the same directory.

```
# File Name, Function/Variables/Wildcard
from file import *
```

Comment: I have done the following. Do you happen to know how to get the x.isdigit() to work? x being a value.

Comment: Add x as a parameter to your function and add `if type(x) == int:` to check if it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this function in your main program and pass an argument. What you want to do between the two files is first set up your function to receive an argument, notice 'x' added in the parenthesis:

```
def checkpoints(x):
        if x.isdigit() == False:
                num = print('Please enter valid interger.')
                return num
        else:
                print('all g')
                return
```

Then in your main where you want to import the file as Clinton showed you above. So if your filename is 'myfunctions.py'  , You can 'import *' from that file, or specifically your function:

```
from myfunctions import checkpoints
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: So if call it and say checkpoints(4) in the main.py the value 4 will be processed if whether its an integer or not? is that the correct understanding?

Comment: yes, you can pass anything into that function that you would like. It will be up to the function to either be able to use what you pass, or check for it before using it so you don't throw an error, or convert it.. so if you know you will pass a string into the function for whatever reason, you can simply first thing in the function say "x = int(x)" to make sure you are passing an integer if that is an issue for you.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in another comment, to import in this way, the file you are importing from should be in the same directory and just use the name without extension at import.

Comment: I have defined that 'x' will be an integer. after importing it to the main program I am getting a positional argument error. I'm afraid I don't know what that is.

Comment: How many arguments are you passing into the function? Also, where are you defining that x will be an integer?

Comment: from chk_one import checkpoints

def main():

    x = int(input(' '))

    checkpoints(x)
    
main()   #this is the main.py#

Comment: your main problem is isdigit. It is a method of the string object meant to tell you if a string has digits inside of it.. so if you pass '1321' as a string, it will return true because those are digits. If you want to make sure it is a positive int, change your if statement to 'if type(x) == int && x > 0" for the check.

Comment: that was backwards, you want type(x) == 'int' && x < 0

Comment: you also might want to try storing your input  in a variable before you ensure it. To test this, just try the function as checkpoints(-1) and checkpoints(1) and see what results you get.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yep, it all checks out correctly. And I know i'm a pain but one last question. The common.py is where the checkpoints is stored if i was to have another function inside the common.py along with the checkpoints what do i need to do to make sure that when checkpoints is called it runs only checkpoints and same applies with the added function?

Comment: What you can do if you have a .py file you are importing with many functions is rather than 'from common import checkpoints', you can do 'import common as c' then refer to the function as c.checkpoints(2)

Comment: additionally, you can just say 'import common' then use the functions as common.checkpoints(2) or common.someFunction() .. etc.. but giving it a short name using 'import common as c' will make a cleaner file

Comment: Also not a pain, glad to help. Plz upvote the answer if it all checks out, thanks Faro!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass in a variable `x` that you have in `main()`, you could just import the function and call it in main as follows.

```py
from common_module import checkpoints  # import the function you want 
..
..
def main():
..
..
  checkpoints(x)  # You can now call this function in main
..
..
```

Note that you'll have to change the definition of `checkpoints` to take in `x` as an argument.